# falcon python example with celery

Tags: celery, falconframework

```
import falcon
import json
from tasks import add
from waitress import serve


class tasksresource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests"""
        self.result = add.delay(1, 2)
        self.context = {'ID': self.result.id, 'final result': self.result.ready()}
        resp.body = json.dumps(self.context)



api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/result', tasksresource())
# api.add_route('/result/task', taskresult())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(api, host='127.1.0.1', port=5555)
```

how do i get the Get the task id from json payload ( post data)
and add a route to it

Comment: As I understood, you want to send task id to another route after starting the task? Is it right?

Comment: Yes also their is term pooling which i dont understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a small example. Structure of files:

```
/project
      __init__.py
      app.py # routes, falcon etc.
      tasks.py # celery 
example.py # script for demonstration how it works
```

app.py:

```
import json

import falcon
from tasks import add
from celery.result import AsyncResult


class StartTask(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        # start task
        task = add.delay(4, 4)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        # return task_id to client
        result = {'task_id': task.id}
        resp.body = json.dumps(result)


class TaskStatus(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp, task_id):
        # get result of task by task_id and generate content to client
        task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
        result = {'status': task_result.status, 'result': task_result.result}
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps(result)


app = falcon.API()

# registration of routes
app.add_route('/start_task', StartTask())
app.add_route('/task_status/{task_id}', TaskStatus())
```

tasks.py:

```
from time import sleep

import celery


app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    """
    :param int x:
    :param int y:
    :return: int
    """
    # sleep just for demonstration
    sleep(5)

    return x + y
```

Now we need to start `celery` application. Go to `project` folder and run:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

After this we need to start `Falcon` application. Go to `project` folder and run:

```
gunicorn app:app
```

Ok. Everything is ready.

`example.py` is small client side which can help to understand:

```
from time import sleep

import requests
# start new task
task_info = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/start_task')
task_info = task_info.json()

while True:
    # check status of task by task_id while task is working
    result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/task_status/' + task_info['task_id'])
    task_status = result.json()

    print task_status

    if task_status['status'] == 'SUCCESS' and task_status['result']:
        print 'Task with id = %s is finished' % task_info['task_id']
        print 'Result: %s' % task_status['result']
        break
    # sleep and check status one more time
    sleep(1)
```

Just call `python ./example.py` and you should see something like this:

```
{u'status': u'PENDING', u'result': None}
{u'status': u'PENDING', u'result': None}
{u'status': u'PENDING', u'result': None}
{u'status': u'PENDING', u'result': None}
{u'status': u'PENDING', u'result': None}
{u'status': u'SUCCESS', u'result': 8}
Task with id = 76542904-6c22-4536-99d9-87efd66d9fe7 is finished
Result: 8
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @DevJalla Good luck in development!

Comment: @DevJalla sorry but I don't know anything about java oauth server

Answer (score 0):

The above example by Danila Ganchar is great and very helpful. I'm using celery version 4.3.0 with Python 3, and one of the errors I received from using the example above is on this line:

```
task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
```

The error I would receive is:

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

This may be a recent change, but `result.AsyncResult` (or just `AsyncResult` in this example because he imported it from celery.result) doesn't know the backend you are using. There are 2 solutions to solving this problem:

1) You can take the AsyncResult of the actual task itself `add.AsyncResult(task_id)` because the `add` task already has the backend defined through the @app.task decorator. The downside to this in this example is you want to be able to get the result for any task by just passing in the task_id via the Falcon endpoint, so this is limited

2) The preferred method is to just pass in the `app` parameter to the AsyncResult function:

```
task = result.AsyncResult(id, app=app)
```

Hope this helps!